# Does a 'weekday' parameter need to be added to unattended upgrade?

Tags: apt, configuration

I wish to change this such that Software Updater will prompt on Sunday mornings rather then Tuesday mornings as it has been. The following are the existing lines of code:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "7";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Will adding `weekday 0;` cause that to happen?